# Override Rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

In my app I have the following routes:

```
  namespace :partners do
    resources :cars
  end
```

And my Car index is the following route:

`'localhost:3000/partners/cars/'`

But I want to have a path like this:

`'localhost:3000/partners/all_cars/'`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
namespace :partners do
  resources :cars, path: 'all_cars', only: [ :index ]
  resources :cars, except: [ :index ]
end
```

The first line will create `/partners/all_cars/` mapping that to `index` action.  Also notice that we are only generating a route for the `index` action specifying `all_cars` path.

The next line, since we already have route for `index`, I suppose we will skip defining `index`, and let other defaults.

Comment: Easy to understand what's happening in your routes with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace :partners do
    resources :cars, except: [:index] do
      collection do
        get :all_cars
      end
  end
end
```

by this you will remove index and add all_cars